# Rails Devise multiple concurrent sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework, devise, mongoid

I am developing a web application using rails and devise for the authentication. There are two types of users, one who are able to have multiple concurrent sessions (super) and the others who can only have a simultaneous session (normal). In order to implement this behaviour, I have added a new field on the User model to store the authentication_token (generated in the SessionsController#create). Also, I added a new filter to the ApplicationController which check if the stored token in the session is equal to the saved on the User model when it is a normal user. When it is not the same authentication token, we logout the normal user.

Now I am developing a new ionic mobile application which needs to login to the same rails application. However, in this case all user types can have multiple concurrent sessions. In order to do this, we would like to continue using devise (although we have also considered to use doorkeeper with password flow).

I am not sure about the best approach to get this. The main problem is to detect if we are accesing the API with the rails or ionic application. One approach is to add a parameter but I don't like to use a parameter in all requests. Another approach it is to use browser gem, but we can access the web from a browser in the mobile.

When we uses the rails application, we can use the same behaviour described above. Otherwise, I think it is not necessary to do anything because devise permits concurrent sessions by default.

Another posibility it is to use a new model to store the authentication token and its type (rails or ionic). If we are using the rails application, then we query the rails authentication token and override it (or create if it does not exist). On the opposite, we add the new authentication_token as a new instance related with the user model. With this behaviour we can manually control the expiration of the tokens and store more information (IP, browser...).

I am not sure about the best approach to achieve this behaviour. Thanks in advance.